# Cocompleteness of enriched categories of algebras

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, monads, enriched-category-theory

A useful result due to [Linton](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0083082) is that for a cocomplete category $C$ and monad $T$ on $C$, if the category of algebras $C^T$ admits [reflexive coequalisers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflexive+coequalizer), then it is cocomplete (see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflexive+coequalizer) for a sketch of a proof).

Are there any analogous results in the literature for *enriched* categories? More specifically, let $V$ be a monoidal category, let $C$ be a $V$-category admitting all weighted colimits, and let $T$ be a $V$-monad on $C$ admitting a $V$-category of algebras $C^T$. Is there a convenient collection of weights $\Phi$ such that, if $C^T$ admits $\Phi$-weighted colimits, then $C^T$ admits all weighted colimits? Ideally when $V = \mathrm{Set}$, this would reduce to Linton's characterisation. (Clearly if $C^T$ admits [conical colimits and copowers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower), it is cocomplete, so I am interested in more minimal assumptions than these.) $V$ may be assumed sufficiently nice.

Comment: For clarity, Fred Linton's result *assumes* that the functor preserves reflexive coequalisers and then makes clever use of their interaction with (infinitary) coproducts.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: it is not necessary to assume that the underlying endofunctor preserves reflexive coequalisers, but when this is true (and $C$ is cocomplete), then in particular $C^T$ has reflexive coequalisers and so is cocomplete.

Comment: Yes, you can assume that the reflexive coequalisers are already there, but I was trying to point out that you don't get them on the cheap. The literature claims that transfinite recursion is needed, but [these seminar slides](http://paultaylor.eu/slides/22-LL-Brum.pdf) shows how they can be found as an example of my version of Pataraia's fixed point theorem.

Comment: I suggest to check the nlab page about the "adjoint lifting theorem". There there is a "formal" treatment of how to propagate cocompleteness from the only existence of coequalizers of reflexive pairs. This might be inspiring for an enriched understanding.